# Is it possible in graph sql to require all inbound relationships to be satisfied when selecting a node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I'm playing around with graph sql as a possible solution to my problem. Essentially it involves creating groups of users -- like described below.

[image]

- There are three employees: Jerry, Kerry, and Larry
- There are two positions: Stocker, and Cashier
- There are two locations: Wichita, and Topeka
- And there are four groups: Topeka Stockers, Topeka  Employees, All Cashiers, and Wichita Cashiers.

The Topeka stockers group doesn't have any members, as there are no employees who are both in the Topeka office and stockers -- The group requires an inbound connection from both the position and office types.

The Topeka Employees group has Jerry and Kerry as members, as it only requires an inbound connection from office types.

The All Cashiers group has Kerry and Larry as members, as it only requires an inbound connection from position types.

The Wichita Cashiers group has Larry as a member, as it requires inbound connections from both the position and office types.

---

Is it possible to issue queries of the type "Which groups is larry a part of" which dynamically determine the number of inbound connections for a given group and determine if there is a path from larry to those groups on all inbound connections?

Comment: what have you tried so far?? Thanks.

Comment: What is "graph sql"? Do you mean Cypher?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that "graph sql" actually means "Cypher".

Also, you don't need to explicitly store the yellow group nodes in the DB, since you can get group information from the rest of the graph. So, I will assume the DB omits the group nodes and the `Dynamic_Assignment` relationships.

Here is how you can create the rest of your sample graph (I used all-caps for the relationship type, to follow the [recommended neo4j naming convention](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/naming/#_recommendations)):

```
MERGE (j:Employee {name: 'Jerry'})
MERGE (k:Employee {name: 'Kerry'})
MERGE (l:Employee {name: 'Larry'})
MERGE (t:Location {name: 'Topeka'})
MERGE (w:Location {name: 'Wichita'})
MERGE (s:Position {name: 'Stocker'})
MERGE (c:Position {name: 'Cashier'})
MERGE (j)-[:ASSIGNED]->(t)
MERGE (k)-[:ASSIGNED]->(t)
MERGE (k)-[:ASSIGNED]->(c)
MERGE (l)-[:ASSIGNED]->(c)
MERGE (l)-[:ASSIGNED]->(w)
```

1. How to get the employees in the "Topeka Employees" group (Jerry, Kerry):

   ```
   MATCH (loc:Location)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(e:Employee)
   WHERE loc.name = 'Topeka'
   RETURN e
   ```
2. How to get the employees in the "All Cashiers" group (Kerry, Larry):

   ```
   MATCH (e:Employee)-[:ASSIGNED]->(p:Position)
   WHERE p.name = 'Cashier'
   RETURN e
   ```
3. How to get the employees in the "Topeka Stockers" group (returns no results):

   ```
   MATCH (loc:Location)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(e:Employee)-[:ASSIGNED]->(p:Position)
   WHERE loc.name = 'Topeka' AND p.name = 'Stocker'
   RETURN e
   ```
4. How to get the employees in the "Wichita Cashiers" group (Larry):

   ```
   MATCH (loc:Location)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(e:Employee)-[:ASSIGNED]->(p:Position)
   WHERE loc.name = 'Wichita' AND p.name = 'Cashier'
   RETURN e
   ```
5. How to find the distinct work-locations and positions that Larry has:

   ```
   MATCH (loc:Location)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(e:Employee)-[:ASSIGNED]->(p:Position)
   WHERE e.name = 'Larry'
   RETURN e, COLLECT(DISTINCT loc.name) AS locations, COLLECT(DISTINCT p.name) AS positions
   ```

   The result (from the "Text" view if using the neo4j Browser):

   ```
   ╒════════════════╤═══════════╤═══════════╕
   │"e"             │"locations"│"positions"│
   ╞════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
   │{"name":"Larry"}│["Wichita"]│["Cashier"]│
   └────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
   ```